# Preferring UITableView's reorder control gesture over custom pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UIPanGestureRecognizer` attached, and by using `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` I'm getting the expected behaviour between my custom gesture and the normal scroll gesture on the table view:

```swift
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return otherGestureRecognizer == scrollView?.panGestureRecognizer
    }
```

The issue is I've broken the table's reordering controls:

[image: Reorder control gesture not working on UITableView]

The reordering gesture starts successfully, but then my custom pan gesture kicks in and breaks it.

I can fix this by requiring other gestures to fail before my custom gesture is recognized:

```swift
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
             shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true  // I need to be more specific in here
}
```

But this is too broad and other things break when I leave this here. I need a way to just target the reorder control's gesture, but I can't find any way to check for it.

Does anyone know how to get a reference to the reorder control's gesture? Or can anyone suggest a different approach to resolve this conflict? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am trying to achieve same thing.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am trying to achieve same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` :

```
panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```